# Distinguishing "assignee" and "watcher" tasks in JIRA

Tags: jira

I want to create a custom filter for displaying JIRA issues, and I am interested in two sorts of tasks:

1. Tasks where I am the assignee and are unresolved.
2. Tasks I am watching.

So the filter I have come up with is the following:

```
(assignee = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved) OR (watcher = currentUser())
```

One doubt I have on the above filter is, **will it display tasks for which there are more people watching aside from me?** As far as I know, there can be only one assignee but multiple watchers. I tried replacing the second statement with `currentUser() in watchers`, but it does not seem to work.

Now, once the tasks are displayed as a list, I don't have a clear view on whether I am an assignee or a watcher for a given task. I could add column "Assignee", but my name is quite long and it takes up unncessary space for other, more relevant columns.

**Is there a simple JIRA field, which allows me to quickly distinguish between assignee and watcher tasks?** For example, ideally, a column where JIRA displays "A" for assignee tasks and "W" for watcher ones. My JIRA version is showing me around 300 fields (but not displaying them all!) so it is a bit like groping in the dark.

Comment: Is there a purpose to your "One doubt I have ..." paragraph? To me it looks like it's either A) unnecessary background noise (and so should be removed) or B) a completely separate question (and so should be asked separately).

Comment: I've been thinking if this question would be on or off-topic for the site. Last time we talked about it, we [considered it on-topic](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286/product-specific-question-e-g-jira), so I'll take a stab on answering it from a leadership perspective.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso thanks, I browsed some questions on the community and observed there were some JIRA-related ones in the same vein as mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - **yes**, in your filter you will have items watched by other people so long you are *also* one of watchers. If you'd like to have a filter where you are the unique watcher, you'd need to also add an exclusion criteria stating that others are not watchers (which is cumbersome and not very effective).

Now, bringing the question to the PM / leadership context - **what you may want to keep track of** is likely to be work you're involved with (by either being the direct person or *one of* the watchers).

How to distinguish them? **All items you're not the assignee, you're the watcher.** You can order your filter by the assignee column and that's it.

Also, notice that on filter results you can select which columns to show, you don't need to show them all (you can even [save your filter with the specific columns](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/save-your-search-as-a-filter/#Savingyoursearchasafilter-clonefilternavigatorcolumnsDefineafilter-specificcolumnorder) you want and then [subscribe to it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/receiving-search-results-via-email-720416706.html).